# Why does this query break when I include a second WHERE condition?

Tags: mysql

The query is

```
SELECT account_id, type_id, client_id, avail_balance 
FROM accounts 
WHERE open_emp_id 
IN (SELECT emp_id 
FROM employee
WHERE (branch_id = 1111) AND (job_id NOT LIKE ‘HD%’);
```

Without the second WHERE condition, the query works fine. With that condition, I get
`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%’))' at line 1`

Comment: If that's your actual query code, it looks like something has substituted "smart quotes" (`‘’`)where you should have single quotes (`''`).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Unbelievable. I've been getting such a headache from all this and it's something that stupid. Thanks. I don't know how to fix this, but maybe I shouldn't be typing these up in TextEdit.

EDIT: Fixed it and still getting a similar issue.

Comment: You miss out one closing bracket @m.lekk

Comment: @learning Thanks. Hopefully someone else can learn from these ridiculous mistakes.